# i Want to pass partialViewName for Html.Partial(string partialViewName) from ViewBag

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

how to pass `ViewBag` string as `string`  :

```
@Html.Partial("'" + @ViewBag.PartialView + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard code for calling partial view

```
 public ActionResult ControllerName()
        {
//here we give our data & pass into result
            return PartialView("SearchPartialView", result);
        }
```

Finally Call Partial View

```
@Html.Partial("ControllerName");
```